# Material UI styled component not releasing DOM Nodes after rerender

Tags: reactjs, dom, material-ui

When I use mui's **styled** function with **shouldForwardProp** option, I watch the browser's Performance monitor and find that everytime my styled component rerender, DOM Nodes are increased without releasing.

Using **sx** prop does make some DOM Nodes release, but most of them are still not released.

I continuously cause rerender for a few minutes and the DOM Nodes are not decreasing. While using non-styled components, DOM Nodes are release afterwards (see the cases that I tested in the `App.tsx` file).

step to recreate:

1. create react app `npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript`
2. go to project folder `cd my-app`
3. install mui `npm install @emotion/react @emotion/styled @mui/material`
4. update `App.tsx`

```
import { Box, Button, styled } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

type MyModel = {
  id: number;
  color: string;
}

const getRandomColor = (): string => {
  var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
  var color = '#';
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
  }
  return color;
}

const StyledBox1 = styled(Box)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: "red"
}));

const StyledBox2 = styled(Box, { shouldForwardProp: prop => prop !== "currentColor" })<{
  currentColor: string;
}>(({ theme, currentColor }) => ({
  backgroundColor: currentColor
}));

function App() {
  const [models, setModels] = useState<MyModel[]>([
    { id: 1, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 2, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 3, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 4, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 5, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 6, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 7, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 8, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 9, color: getRandomColor() },
    { id: 10, color: getRandomColor() },
  ]);

  const clickHandler = () => {
    const newModels: MyModel[] = [...models];
    newModels[0].color = getRandomColor();
    setModels(newModels);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {/* ✅ */}
      {/* {models.map(model => <Box key={model.id}>{model.id}</Box>)} */}

      {/* ✅ */}
      {/* {models.map(model => <StyledBox1 key={model.id}>{model.id}</StyledBox1>)} */}

      {/* ❌ */}
      {models.map(model => <StyledBox2 key={model.id} currentColor={model.color}>{model.id}</StyledBox2>)}

      {/* ❌ */}
      {/* <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[0].color}>{models[0].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[1].color}>{models[1].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[2].color}>{models[2].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[3].color}>{models[3].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[4].color}>{models[4].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[5].color}>{models[5].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[6].color}>{models[6].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[7].color}>{models[7].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[8].color}>{models[8].id}</StyledBox2>
      <StyledBox2 currentColor={models[9].color}>{models[9].id}</StyledBox2> */}

      {/* ❌ */}
      {/* <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[0].color }}>{models[0].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[1].color }}>{models[1].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[2].color }}>{models[2].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[3].color }}>{models[3].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[4].color }}>{models[4].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[5].color }}>{models[5].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[6].color }}>{models[6].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[7].color }}>{models[7].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[8].color }}>{models[8].id}</Box>
      <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: models[9].color }}>{models[9].id}</Box> */}

      {/* ✅ */}
      {/* <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[0].color }}>{models[0].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[1].color }}>{models[1].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[2].color }}>{models[2].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[3].color }}>{models[3].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[4].color }}>{models[4].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[5].color }}>{models[5].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[6].color }}>{models[6].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[7].color }}>{models[7].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[8].color }}>{models[8].id}</div>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: models[9].color }}>{models[9].id}</div> */}

      <Button variant="contained" onClick={clickHandler}>Update Color</Button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My `package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.12",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

5. start app `npm start`
6. click the only button on the screen multiple times to cause the components to rerender and watch Performance monitor

In the picture, I cause DOM Nodes go from 150+ to 1500+.

This might doesn't seem so bad but I having an app that has multiple styled MuiSlider with small step which can easily make DOM Nodes over 50.000+, my app got very lag after that.

I'm not sure I am using styled function the right way or is there something that I missed.

Please help!

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WY2o4.png)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This issue happened because I used a very dynamic prop for `styled` function which lead to MUI created a css class for every different color, the solution is to use `style` prop for this kind of dynamic color property.

Reference to this answer: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/36294#issuecomment-1462495889